# Erro ao inserir Apóstrofo em componente que usa Auto Complete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocompletar

Estou tendo problemas com a inserção do `'` Apóstrofo quando vou fazer uma busca pelo componente `AutoComplete` do `Jquery UI`.

## Jquery

```
 $("#<%=txtHipotePai.ClientID%>").autocomplete({
     source: function(request, response) {

         $.ajax({
             url: '<%=ResolveUrl("../ws/AutoComplete.asmx/GetListaHipotese")%>',
             data: "{ 'prefixText': '" + 'pt-Br' +
                 "','idioma': '" + $("#<%=rblIdioma.ClientID%> :checked").val() + "'}",
             dataType: "json",
             type: "POST",
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             success: function(data) {
                 response($.map(data.d, function(item) {
                     return {
                         label: item.split('#')[1],
                         val: item.split('#')[0]
                     }
                 }))
             },
             error: function(response) {
                 alert(response.responseText);
             },
             failure: function(response) {
                 alert(response.responseText);
             }
         });
     },
     select: function(e, i) {
         $("#<%=hdfCodHipotesePai.ClientID%>").val(i.item.val);
     },
     minLength: 1
 });
```

Comment: Por favor, edite sua pergunta acrescentando o código JavaScript relacionado ao campo.

Comment: Não é recomendável colocar erros como imagens externas. Nem sempre elas estão acessíveis a todos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema ocorre porque você está tentando gerar o Json a partir de concatenações de String, e no momento em que você concatena uma String contendo aspas simples o Json quebra.

Por exemplo:

```js
{ 'prefixText': 'pt-Br','idioma': 'aqui tem ' aspas simples' }
```

Note que a sintaxe do Json acima está corrompida.

Seria mais produtivo criar um objeto de verdade, depois serializar para Json.

Exemplo:

```js
...
data: JSON.stringify({
    'prefixText': 'pt-Br',
    'idioma': $("#<%=rblIdioma.ClientID%> :checked").val()
}),
...
```

Veja se assim funciona.