# Input e Json problemas com aspas

Tags: javascript, json

Olá. 
Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação web usando o SpringFrontEnd e uma API Restful na backend.
A front está em javascript pegando dados da API. 
Eis que houve um problema....

Ao entrar com aspas algum campo em algum Input ou Textarea
Ele quebra o código e retorna 400.

Se o JSON que pego dos inputs tem aspas " " e insiro no input ' para testes ele retorna o erro.
    Unexpected character ('"' (code 34)): was expecting comma to separate      OBJECT entries 
    at [Source:    org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableInput     Stream@36f8cabd; line: 1, column: 26]

Eis que pergunto. É recomendável mecher todo os lugares que faço a concatenação do JSON pro Ajax mandar pra API. 
Ou criar uma função global para remover as aspas duplas ou simples de todo os input e textarea?

Lembrando que meu projeto é imenso, mais de 40 páginas .jsp de view e várias na API. 
Quais sugestões me dão? Obrigado, no guardo.

Comment: Seria algo do tipo? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/41662/erro-ao-inserir-ap%C3%B3strofo-em-componente-que-usa-auto-complete

Comment: Seria isso mesmo Marconi, desculpe responder agora. O complicado é que tenho vários JSON no projeto criado a partir de concatenações de String. Agora é hora de perder umas horinhas ajustando e testando pra ver se não da erro. No cenário atual eu bloquiei as aspas nos inputs e textareas com uma função. Resolveu, porém existem casos que as aspas vão ser necessárias para inclusão. Obrigado pelo post.

Comment: Bom que pude ajudar.